# Efficient encoding algorithm for sparse vector

Tags: c, encoding, run-length-encoding

Does anyone know how to compress(encoding) the sparse vector?
the sparse vector means `1xN` matrix that have many "0".

for example

```
10000000000001110000000000000000100000000
```

above is the example of **sparse vector**.

Ofcourse, I know the run length algorithm.
I want other algorithm for encoding this type of vector.
help me plz...

Comment: First you need to define what you mean with "efficient": Are you aiming for the best possible compression, or for the best possible execution performance for some calculations?

Comment: What have you otherwise found using your research? Just going to your favorite search engine should have given you plenty of hits of both generic algorithms as well as specific implementations.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "efficient"? Taking up little space? Being fast to encode? Being fast to decode? Something else?

Comment: What's wrong with RLE?

Comment: Your example screams "Run length encoding". Please explain which requirements forbid it. This might also shed some light on the unclear meaning of "efficient" in your question.

Comment: Saved as bits inside bytes, the data is already compacted by a factor 8, which, on the given example, probably beats the binary representation of any compression you could do.

Answer (score 1):

Use modified Huffman coding, as suggested in the source code on this site: https://www.programminglogic.com/implementing-huffman-coding-in-c/. This is used in FAXs and it is a common knowledge that the modified Huffman is the first improvement over the simple run-length-encoding that you have already figured out. Note that this is generally used for ASCII, but you may implement it for any stream as long as you may determine which combination of bits are more frequent than the others.